# Removing plusone.js and widgets.js

Tags: blogger

It seems like the `&lt;!--</body>--&gt; &lt;/body&gt;` trick doesn't work anymore. Anyone here knows how to remove those JavaScript files?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good way to do it

replace `<head>` With

```
&lt;!--<head>--&gt;<b:include name='body'/>&lt;head&gt;
```

the replace `</head><body>` with the following

```
    &lt;!--</head>--&gt;&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body itemscope=&#39;itemscope&#39; itemtype=&#39;http://schema.org/WebPage&#39;&gt;
```

at last replace `</body>` with

```
&lt;/body&gt;
```

this will remove all the default styling and js and quote them above the head it`s much better than

```
`<!--</body>-->`
```

Answer (score 0):

It still works. you can be sure that by pressing `CTRL+U` then scroll bottom and make sure the JavaScript code between the comment `<!--      </body>-->`

Comment: Send your link please.